# Mixing Blazor Components, DI and C# 8 nullable

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor, .net-5

I am using .net 5 for a Blazor app in a project with nullable enabled. It is using Code Behind to create Blazor Components. I want to use a constructor so that I can avoid marking every non DI property as nullable to simplify accessing them in my blazor code. However, If I create a constructor like
`public PageNumberOne(ILogger<PrimaryItem> logger) {}`

I get the error **MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type**

If I use the inject attribute on the DI items then I have the warning - **Non-nullable property _logger must contain a non-null value when exciting the constructor**

So how do I mix DI with nullable without just marking every property as nullable?

I could also create them in the main body of the "code" block but then I cannot access my DI items for initialization because they are not available until the OnInitialized. So again I have to mark them as Nullable.

Comment: You can make constructor injection work if you use a `.razor.cs` code behind file.  See the solution presented here:  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18088#issuecomment-714452447

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Microsoft advice from [Request a service in a component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#request-a-service-in-a-component) at ASP.NET Core Blazor dependency injection documentation:

> Since injected services are expected to be available, don't mark injected services as nullable. Instead, assign a default literal with the null-forgiving operator (default!).

```cs
[Inject]
private IExampleService ExampleService { get; set; } = default!;
```

Comment: Alternatively, just assume injection will work and declare the property like `public NavigationManager MyNavigationManager {get; set;} = default!;`

Comment: @KirkWoll, really? I must to try it!!! Looks like a better solution!!

Comment: @KirkWoll, I just tested it injecting via interface like `[Inject] private IWeatherForecastService ForecastService { get; set; } = default!;`  and it runs like a charm. WTF, how an interface can be instantiated as `default!`? Are you so kind to post your comment as an answer to delete mine and vote-up your approach? Regards.

Comment: Your answer is fine, thanks for the credit. :)  But the explanation is quite simple.  For an interface or class, `default` is just `null`.  The `!` operator doesn't do anything at runtime, it merely reassures the compiler that it will in fact be not null.  The important thing to remember is that all the nullability stuff introduced recently is handled by the compiler, not the runtime.

Comment: @KirkWoll: https://twitter.com/ctrl_alt_d/status/1364521983225065475?s=20   :)

Comment: Looks like using assigning `default!` to Blazor injected services is officially recommended. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0